# Hadoop MRUnit IllegalStateException when using Hadoop-The Definitive Guide code

Tags: java, hadoop, mrunit

I am studying Hadoop from the Definitive Guide book and tried to execute this piece of code which is resulting in the error.
Example from Chapter-5. Link to Github code:
source:
https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch05/src/main/java/v1/MaxTemperatureMapper.java

```
public class MaxTemperatureMapper
    extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    String year = line.substring(15, 19);
    int airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(87, 92));
    context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
}
```

}

test: 
https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch05/src/test/java/v1/MaxTemperatureMapperTest.java

```
public class MaxTemperatureMapperTest {
@Test
public void processesValidRecord() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Text value = new Text("0043011990999991950051518004+68750+023550FM-12+0382" +
            "99999V0203201N00261220001CN9999999N9-00111+99999999999");
    new MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>()
            .withMapper(new MaxTemperatureMapper())
            .withInputValue(value)
            .withOutput(new Text("1950"), new IntWritable(-11))
            .runTest();
}
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input was provided
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.preRunChecks(MapDriverBase.java:286)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.mapreduce.MapDriver.run(MapDriver.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:640)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.runTest(TestDriver.java:627)
at book.hadoopdefinitiveguide.chap5.examples.MaxTemperatureMapperTest.processesValidRecord(MaxTemperatureMapperTest.java:12)
```

This happens to be the first code I'm executing in hadoop and it is throwing this error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a key and a value, you only supplied the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Thomas Junblut pointed out, you need to specify a key along with the value.

But (assuming you're using mrunit 1.0 or higher), [`withInputKey|Value` is deprecated](http://mrunit.apache.org/documentation/javadocs/1.0.0/index.html). You should instead be using [`withInput(K1 key, V1 val)`](http://mrunit.apache.org/documentation/javadocs/1.0.0/index.html), where you specify bot the key and value in one method, instead of `withInputValue(..).withInputKey(..)`. So you'd have something like this

```
new MapDriver<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>()
        .withMapper(new MaxTemperatureMapper())
        .withInput(new LongWritable(), value)
        .withOutput(new Text("1950"), new IntWritable(-11))
        .runTest();
```

The `new LongWritable()` is just an arbitrary key.

---

**EDIT**

So after further testing, it's not a problem with your code (except for the deprecation, but that isn't the cause).

I ran the same test using the code I posted and got the exact same error. I tested with some old practice project I had. It seemed to be a problem with the classes not being built correctly. I created a whole new project, rewrote (copy-paste) the mapper class and created a new test case, saved everything, ran it, and it worked fine. Try to do this. BTW I'm on eclipse using the Eclipse Hadoop plugin to create the MR Project